# Angular Form Validation, Save button always disabled

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation

I have an angular form where the questions are specified in an array.

The HTML is as follows:

```
<form ng-controller="SupplierController" name="newSupplierForm">

  <p>Enter details for the new Supplier. The new supplier will be added to category {{selectedCategory.description}}</p>

  <p ng-repeat="field in formfields">
     <label class="field" for="{{field.name}}" ng-hide="newSupplierForm.{{field.name}}.$dirty && (newSupplierForm.{{field.name}}.$error.required || newSupplierForm.{{field.name}}.$invalid)">{{field.caption}}</label>
     <label class="error" for="{{field.name}}" ng-show="newSupplierForm.{{field.name}}.$dirty && (newSupplierForm.{{field.name}}.$error.required  || newSupplierForm.{{field.name}}.$invalid)">{{field.caption}}</label>
     <input type="{{field.type}}" name="{{field.name}}" ng-model="newSupplier[field.name]" ng-required="{{field.required}}">    
  </p>
  <button ng-disabled="newSupplierForm.$invalid" ng-click="saveSupplier()">Save</button>

</form>
```

The Controller is:

```
financeApp.controller('SupplierController', function($scope, $http) {

$scope.formfields = [
    {caption:'Name :', name:'name', required:"true", type:"text"},
    {caption:'Address :', name:'address1', required:"true", type:"text"},
    {caption:' :', name:'address2', required:"true", type:"text"},
    {caption:' :', name:'address3', required:"", type:"text"},
    {caption:' :', name:'address4', required:"", type:"text"},
    {caption:'Post Code :', name:'postcode', required:"", type:"text"},
    {caption:'Email :', name:'email', required:"", type:"email"},
    {caption:'Phone :', name:'phone', required:"", type:"text"}
];

$scope.newSupplier = {};

$scope.saveSupplier = function() {
    $http.post('/finance/supplier', newSupplier).success(function(data) {
        alert(data);
    });     
}

});
```

It all appears to work correctly, except that the Save button is never enabled, even if the form is valid. The research I've done so far would indicate that this should work, but it does not.

Example : [Disable a button if at least one input field is empty using ngDisabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26162289/disable-a-button-if-at-least-one-input-field-is-empty-using-ngdisabled)

What am I doing wrong?

Also, is there any way of improving this code generally? This is my first attempt at Angular.

Comment: Um, it actually works. When all input is valid the button is no longer disabled. Which version of Angular do you use?

Comment: Add this to the end of your form `<pre>{{ newSupplierForm.$error | json }}</pre>`. It'll show you the form's errors.

Comment: Fixed - I was doing something else wrong. Silly me.

Answer (score 1):

Try `ng-required="field.required"`, without the curly braces, as this already expects an angular expression.

And inside the controller, treat the `required` as true or false, not as a string.

---

As for how to improve this, the approach you used is ok, but if your form will always have the same fields (it's not dynamic), you should create html elements for each field, and not declare them inside the controller.

The controller should control the **behaviour** of the view, not what fields to display (in a non dynamic point of view).